# What query parameters does Bing have?

Tags: search-engine, bing

I'm writing a bookmarklet<sup>[1]</sup> for Bing, and would like to customise my search.

The bookmarklet URL takes the form of:

```
https://www.bing.com/search?q=%s&some=other&parameters=etc
```

After quite a bit of searching and experimenting, I have found:

```
q          # search keywords
count      # how many results per page
adlt       # safe search (strict, moderate, off)
cc         # ISO 3166 country code
setlang    # set interface language, e.g. fr-fr, en-us
lf=1       # pages only in the same language as the interface
format=rss # get result page as RSS
```

What other parameters are there? I am, in particular, interested in restricting the results to pages in a certain language.

<sub>[1] Technically, a [Mozilla custom keyword](https://www-archive.mozilla.org/docs/end-user/keywords.html).</sub>

Comment: Have you found a solution? Doing something similar, and I'd like to know what all those parameters are and what I can use.

Answer (score 4):

Here are few more Bing query parameters:

1. freshness
2. mkt
3. offset
4. responseFilter
5. safeSearch
6. textFormat
7. textDecorations

Please refer the following link to know more about these [query parameters](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cognitiveservices/bing-web-api-v5-reference#query-parameters) for Bing:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cognitiveservices/bing-web-api-v5-reference#query-parameters